# Cisco ASA 5512 one download blocks all others until download finishes

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, bandwidth

My company has a 50 Mbps Down/Up connection. I just migrated from a PIX 515E to an ASA 5512. Previously, one user could download a large file from the internet and block all other users from accessing the internet until the download finished. I assumed this was a limitation of the PIX not being able to handle the 50 Mbps connection. When we had a 20 Mbps connection *ca* 2016 we didn't have this problem.

However, even with the ASA installed, we still have this problem. This doesn't seem like a QoS thing because it's not HTTP/S vs. FTP; rather one HTTP/S download blocks all other HTTP/S downloads.

It seems that if one user starts a download at 50 Mbps and a 2nd user needs to download something, the ASA should then allocate 25 Mbps to each user. Is this something I have to configure manually?

**EDIT: output requested.**

Output of `show resource usage` (`show resource usage all detail` too long)

```
ASA-Primary# sh resource usage
Resource                 Current        Peak      Limit        Denied Context
SSH Server                     1           1          5             0 System
ASDM                           1           2         30             0 System
Syslogs [rate]                 0           8        N/A             0 System
Conns                        874        2312     100000             0 System
Xlates                       755        2151        N/A             0 System
Hosts                       9246        9417        N/A             0 System
Conns [rate]                  11         204        N/A             0 System
Inspects [rate]                2          52        N/A             0 System
Routes                        15          15  unlimited             0 System
```

**Running config, scrubbed**:

```
!
ASA Version 9.2(2)4 
!
hostname ASA-Primary
domain-name domain.example.com
enable password redactedredacted encrypted
xlate per-session permit tcp any4 any6
xlate per-session permit tcp any6 any6
xlate per-session permit tcp any4 any4
xlate per-session permit udp any6 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session permit udp any6 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session permit tcp any6 any4
xlate per-session permit udp any4 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session permit udp any4 any4 eq domain
passwd redactedredacted encrypted
names
dns-guard
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address FF.SS.TT.35 255.255.255.224 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.14.2 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 nameif dmz1
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.16.8.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 nameif dmz2
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.16.137.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 description ASA-Primary Management port
 management-only
 nameif management
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.3.8.99 255.255.252.0 
!
banner login *** WARNING -- ACCESS TO THIS SYSTEM IS PROHIBITED ***
boot system disk0:/asa922-4-smp-k8.bin
boot system disk0:/asa902-smp-k8.bin
boot system disk0:/asa861-2-smp-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
dns domain-lookup inside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 10.3.8.7
 name-server 10.3.0.3
 domain-name domain.example.com
object network inside-10.3
 subnet 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network inside-172.16.138
 subnet 172.16.138.0 255.255.255.0
object network inside-172.16.136
 subnet 172.16.136.0 255.255.255.0
object network inside-172.16.139
 subnet 172.16.139.0 255.255.255.0
object network EndUserIP-soandso1
 host re.dac.t.ed
object network EndUserIP-soandso2
 host re.dac.t.ed
object network EndUserIP-soandso3
 host re.dac.t.ed
object network EndUserIP-soandso4
 host re.dac.t.ed
object network OutsideVendor-1
 subnet 206.160.83.0 255.255.255.0
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host033
 host FF.SS.TT.33
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host034
 host FF.SS.TT.34
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host035
 host FF.SS.TT.35
 description External WAN IP FF.SS.TT.35/27 on primary ISP, Global WAN IP
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host036
 host FF.SS.TT.36
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host037
 host FF.SS.TT.37
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host038
 host FF.SS.TT.38
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host039
 host FF.SS.TT.39
 description External WAN IP FF.SS.TT.39/27 on primary ISP, external SSH
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host040
 host FF.SS.TT.40
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host041
 host FF.SS.TT.41
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host042
 host FF.SS.TT.42
 description External WAN IP FF.SS.TT.42/27 on primary ISP, WWW
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host043
 host FF.SS.TT.43
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host044
 host FF.SS.TT.44
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host045
 host FF.SS.TT.45
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host046
 host FF.SS.TT.46
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host047
 host FF.SS.TT.47
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host048
 host FF.SS.TT.48
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host049
 host FF.SS.TT.49
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host050
 host FF.SS.TT.50
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host051
 host FF.SS.TT.51
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host052
 host FF.SS.TT.52
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host053
 host FF.SS.TT.53
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host054
 host FF.SS.TT.54
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host055
 host FF.SS.TT.55
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host056
 host FF.SS.TT.56
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host057
 host FF.SS.TT.57
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host058
 host FF.SS.TT.58
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host059
 host FF.SS.TT.59
 description External WAN IP FF.SS.TT.59/27 on primary ISP, FTP
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host060
 host FF.SS.TT.60
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host061
 host FF.SS.TT.61
object network wanIP-ISP1-Host062
 host FF.SS.TT.62
object network workstationIP-1
 host 10.3.9.99
object network serverIP-clock
 host 172.16.137.50
object network serverIP-vxx1
 host 172.16.8.8
object network serverIP-INCWeb
 host 172.16.138.145
object network serverIP-Proxy
 host 172.16.8.53
object network serverIP-proof
 host 172.16.137.60
object network serverIP-FTP
 host 10.3.8.48
object network serverIP-NewerFTP
 host 10.3.8.148
object network serverIP-bud
 host 10.3.8.88
object network serverIP-vxx2
 host 10.3.4.250
object network serverIP-syslog
 host 10.3.9.86
object network serverIP-smart
 host 172.16.137.5
object network serverIP-www
 host 172.16.137.42
object network serverIP-Webmail
 host 172.16.137.30
object network serverIP-DC1
 host 10.3.0.3
object network serverIP-edgcap
 host 10.3.24.5
object network serverIP-m1
 host 10.3.12.14
object network serverIP-m2
 host 10.3.12.15
object network serverIP-m3
 host 10.3.12.25
object network vpn-tunnelrs-site1
 subnet 10.191.5.0 255.255.255.248
object network vpn-tunnelrs-site2
 subnet 10.191.37.0 255.255.255.248
object network vpn-tunnelvanco-group-10
 subnet 10.100.10.0 255.255.255.0
object network vpn-tunnelvanco-group-20
 subnet 10.100.20.0 255.255.255.0
object network vpn-tunnelvanco-group-30
 subnet 10.100.30.0 255.255.255.0
object network vpn-tunnelvanco-group-40
 subnet 10.100.40.0 255.255.255.0
object network vpn-fin
 subnet 172.16.0.0 255.255.252.0
object network serverIP-INCWeb
 host 10.3.9.141
object network serverIP-INCWebVlan5
 host 172.16.138.141
object-group network oldspamfilter
 description all oldspamfilter and google app ip addresses
 network-object 64.18.0.0 255.255.240.0
 network-object 64.223.160.0 255.255.224.0
 network-object 66.102.0.0 255.255.224.0
 network-object 66.249.80.0 255.255.240.0
 network-object 72.14.192.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 74.125.0.0 255.255.0.0
 network-object 173.194.0.0 255.255.0.0
 network-object 207.126.144.0 255.255.240.0
 network-object 209.85.128.0 255.255.128.0
 network-object 216.239.32.0 255.255.224.0
object-group network DenyBadHosts
 description Use this group to block access from inside to out
 network-object host 63.209.213.22
 network-object host 63.211.120.39
 network-object host 66.151.158.177
 network-object host 66.98.192.81
 network-object host 81.173.5.198
 network-object host 172.16.253.162
 network-object host 207.44.246.72
 network-object host 217.64.35.211
object-group network inside-nets
 description All the internal LAN addresses
 network-object object inside-10.3
 network-object object inside-172.16.138
 network-object object inside-172.16.136
 network-object object inside-172.16.139
object-group network cloudproduct
 network-object 4.232.123.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network ExternalAccess-FTPServer
 description Access group to allow WWW/HTTPS on the FTP Server
 network-object object OutsideVendor-1
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso4
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso3
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso1
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso2
object-group network ExternalAccess-syslog
 description Access group to allow SSH
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso1
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso2
object-group network ExternalAccess-RDP
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso4
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso3
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso1
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso2
object-group network access-ssh
 description This is for allowing SSH access.
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso1
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso4
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso3
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso2
object-group network ExternalAccess-NewerFTP
 description Allow certain services to the Newer FTP server
 network-object object EndUserIP-soandso1
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1
 group-object cloudproduct
 group-object oldspamfilter
object-group icmp-type DM_INLINE_ICMP_1
 icmp-object echo
 icmp-object echo-reply
 icmp-object time-exceeded
 icmp-object unreachable
object-group icmp-type DM_INLINE_ICMP_2
 icmp-object echo
 icmp-object echo-reply
 icmp-object time-exceeded
 icmp-object unreachable
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_2
 service-object esp 
 service-object udp destination eq 4500 
 service-object udp destination eq isakmp 
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_1 tcp
 port-object eq 8080
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_10 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
 port-object eq pop3
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_11 tcp
 port-object eq ftp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_12 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_13 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_2 tcp
 port-object eq 3876
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_3 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_4 tcp
 port-object eq 2052
 port-object range 28000 30000
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_5 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_6 tcp
 port-object range 38700 39699
 port-object eq ftp
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_7 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_8 tcp
 port-object range 38700 39699
 port-object eq ftp
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_9 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group protocol TCPUDP
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_3
 service-object tcp destination eq smtp 
 service-object tcp-udp destination eq domain 
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_5
 service-object tcp-udp destination eq 20000 
 service-object tcp destination eq 2051 
 service-object tcp destination eq 2737 
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_14 tcp
 port-object eq 8080
 port-object eq ftp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group network vpn-vanco
 network-object object vpn-tunnelvanco-group-10
 network-object object vpn-tunnelvanco-group-20
 network-object object vpn-tunnelvanco-group-30
 network-object object vpn-tunnelvanco-group-40
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2
 network-object 172.16.8.0 255.255.255.0
 group-object inside-nets
 network-object 172.16.137.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3
 network-object 172.16.137.0 255.255.255.0
 group-object inside-nets
 network-object 172.16.8.0 255.255.255.0
object-group icmp-type DM_INLINE_ICMP_3
 icmp-object echo
 icmp-object echo-reply
 icmp-object time-exceeded
 icmp-object unreachable
object-group icmp-type DM_INLINE_ICMP_4
 icmp-object echo
 icmp-object echo-reply
 icmp-object time-exceeded
 icmp-object unreachable
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_15 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_16 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_6
 service-object esp 
 service-object udp destination eq 4500 
 service-object udp destination eq isakmp 
access-list InsideToOut extended deny ip any object-group DenyBadHosts 
access-list InsideToOut extended permit ip object-group inside-nets any inactive 
access-list InsideToOut extended permit ip any any inactive 
access-list InsideToOut extended permit object-group TCPUDP any any 
access-list InsideToOut extended permit icmp any any object-group DM_INLINE_ICMP_2 
access-list InsideToOut remark This AL is for LAN-to-WAN communication, applied to inside int, incoming traffic
access-list OutsideToIn extended deny ip object-group DenyBadHosts any 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit icmp any any object-group DM_INLINE_ICMP_1 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp object-group access-ssh object serverIP-syslog eq ssh 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1 any object serverIP-smart eq domain inactive 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1 object serverIP-smart eq smtp inactive 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_2 any object serverIP-vxx1 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-www object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_1 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp object-group access-ssh object serverIP-vxx2 eq ssh 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-vxx2 object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_2 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object wanIP-ISP1-Host044 object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_9 inactive 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-Webmail object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_10 inactive 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object wanIP-ISP1-Host046 object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_11 inactive 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object wanIP-ISP1-Host047 object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_12 inactive 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-INCWeb object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_3 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object wanIP-ISP1-Host051 object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_13 inactive 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-proxy object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_4 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-clock object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_15 inactive 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-proof object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_16 inactive 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-bud object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_5 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-FTP object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_6 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp object-group ExternalAccess-FTPServer object serverIP-FTP object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_7 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp any object serverIP-NewerFTP object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_8 
access-list OutsideToIn extended permit tcp object-group ExternalAccess-RDP object workstationIP-jb2 eq 3389 
access-list OutsideToIn remark This AL is for WAN-to-LAN communication, applied to outside int, incoming traffic
access-list dmz2_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_3 object serverIP-smart object-group inside-nets inactive 
access-list dmz2_access_in extended permit tcp object serverIP-www any object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_14 
access-list dmz2_access_in extended permit tcp object serverIP-www object serverIP-INCWebVlan5 eq 1433 
access-list dmz2_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1 object serverIP-www object serverIP-DC1 eq domain 
access-list dmz2_access_in extended permit icmp 172.16.137.0 255.255.255.0 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2 object-group DM_INLINE_ICMP_3 
access-list dmz1_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_6 object serverIP-vxx1 any 
access-list dmz1_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1 object serverIP-proxy object serverIP-DC1 eq domain 
access-list dmz1_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_5 object serverIP-proxy object serverIP-edgcap 
access-list dmz1_access_in extended permit icmp 172.16.8.0 255.255.255.0 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3 object-group DM_INLINE_ICMP_4 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging emblem
logging console errors
logging trap errors
logging asdm errors
logging from-address ASA-Primary@domain.example.com
logging recipient-address redacted@domain.example.com level errors
logging device-id hostname
logging host management 10.3.8.100 format emblem
logging host management 10.3.9.86
logging debug-trace
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu dmz1 1500
mtu dmz2 1500
mtu management 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-731-101.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,outside) source static serverIP-syslog wanIP-ISP1-Host039
nat (dmz2,outside) source static serverIP-smart wanIP-ISP1-Host040
nat (dmz1,outside) source static serverIP-vxx1 wanIP-ISP1-Host041
nat (dmz2,outside) source static serverIP-www wanIP-ISP1-Host042
nat (inside,outside) source static serverIP-vxx2 wanIP-ISP1-Host043
nat (dmz2,outside) source static serverIP-Webmail wanIP-ISP1-Host045
nat (inside,outside) source static serverIP-INCWeb wanIP-ISP1-Host048
nat (dmz1,outside) source static serverIP-proxy wanIP-ISP1-Host053
nat (dmz2,outside) source static serverIP-proof wanIP-ISP1-Host055
nat (inside,outside) source static serverIP-bud wanIP-ISP1-Host057
nat (inside,outside) source static serverIP-FTP wanIP-ISP1-Host059
nat (inside,outside) source static serverIP-NewerFTP wanIP-ISP1-Host060
nat (inside,outside) source static workstationIP-jb2 wanIP-ISP1-Host062
!
object network inside-10.3
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network inside-172.16.138
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network inside-172.16.136
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network inside-172.16.139
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
access-group OutsideToIn in interface outside
access-group InsideToOut in interface inside
access-group dmz1_access_in in interface dmz1
access-group dmz2_access_in in interface dmz2
access-group InsideToOut in interface management
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FF.SS.TT.33 1
route inside 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0 172.16.14.1 1
route inside 172.16.136.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.14.1 1
route inside 172.16.138.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.14.1 1
route inside 172.16.139.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.14.1 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication http console LOCAL 
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
http server enable
http server idle-timeout 30
http 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0 management
snmp-server host management 10.3.8.100 community *****
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server community domainx
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0
 enrollment self
 subject-name CN=10.3.8.99,CN=ASA-Primary
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0
 certificate de3b56b6
    dcca47ce 2ab256ea 73e8b438 b5343658 039afd17 33c89acc 3bb88d3c 23aa8f8d
    fe2637bf f975a578 42e4ded6 1fc3019f 3dd50ad8 1d664d5a 5c732327 31d13864
    b7252051 2bbdd613 2c7e8a9d 28c4fb77 a952e739 bdb56818 171f87bd c9901844
    62e19b16 b3c6196d f19d5498 091853da c20d9c4a 15c017d4 6787eacc 207a97d0
    8a216da2 689bf587 da9187d0 fea8a437 082ff6a8 c6797d53 2015ee13 a00eb3ab
    bc484059 0efac2a7 7579da75 3df90528 e56e004c c5356289 10a90e89 10b0d275
    f3cae516 2e20b1bf 0c5754ea f6a2f8f5 37324067 c9551e10 7e929dc1 9a897405
    2bcdd584 e423e95b 92ad328c f396cfb4 f2321928 fdd51911 7eeed1da 2c8410e3
    5d9a1b6c 2bef3f80 9bae84ef 70a641f3 34d7aea1 01e863b1 0bd2d027 ee09d795
    bb91a799 d77a0eb4 ea5fbcc4 67523724 eea8aa3e 7fab421a b4b419b7 63daf90c
    91849dfb 7d7c5bd6 50c3ab86 e0faad99 d69913c2 61d4db08 00798434 1a6316a7
    f25ba250 ed435c47 3081a891 c34c4ef1 314bfe42 57a360f1 74358a3e 5470affb
    a4736d51 9183b322 450c4c63 8e810d2b b29ac9a3 f68a5a5b 92eeff9a d312566a
    3aaed420 0392906c 4bb88800 0a7b1ca9 60edcb8b 888afe1a d5b8c317 5949c6fd
    03566452 6391e8c0 8965560c 218341a1 d2b9edc5 afa5fd1f 16810622 f44cdd40
    94387d0c 3372a1b5 31393406 40ebb5af 91451161 aa1ee356 707d052b 33faaf83
    cd
  quit
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
!!!!! Crypto policies removed.
crypto ikev1 policy 150
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0 management
telnet timeout 30
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh pubkey-chain
  server 10.3.8.24
    key-hash sha256 ef:ce:99:44:f5:8c:60:56:bb:e8:61:00:40:c1:83:95:da:bd:99:6e:23:ff:aa:11:9a:95:9f:7f:c2:e5:7d:88
ssh 10.3.0.0 255.255.0.0 management
ssh 172.16.13.0 255.255.255.0 management
ssh timeout 60
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics host
threat-detection statistics port
threat-detection statistics protocol
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
ntp server 10.3.0.3 source inside
ntp server 10.3.8.7 source inside prefer
ssl trust-point ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0 management vpnlb-ip
ssl trust-point ASDM_Launcher_Access_TrustPoint_0 management
webvpn
 anyconnect-essentials
username admin password 90914faa252c87b4 encrypted
username soandso1 password 4e9c4a964337bd60 encrypted privilege 15
username soandso2 password b573e047c82d0d81 encrypted privilege 15
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
 class class-default
  user-statistics accounting
!
service-policy global_policy global
smtp-server 92.24.131.6
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment
  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly 18
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly 18
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:4bafe8c52c88da32c6aede34d020b7e3
: end
```

Comment: First, please provide us with a sanitized output of your running configuration. Next, how do you know the ASA is "blocking" the other connections? When it happens, can do you issue the `show resource usage` command and show us the output?  Are there any log entries of the ASA dropping the other traffic when it happens?

Comment: @JesseP. , it'll take some time to sanitize it. I first suspected the PIX as being the bottleneck because during one such download, I couldn't RDP into a machine on one of the DMZs; after the large download I could RDP into it. Below the ASA we have a 4507. That wouldn't be the bottleneck because we transfer backups and other content within the LAN at full Gb speeds and that doesn't have an effect on internet resources.

I haven't tried the same test on the ASA (today is 0 day for that unit). I'll also observe the `show resource usage` output too.

Comment: I'll be curious to see the config and the result of the resource usage command. I have a guess of what's going on but don't want to jump the gun until I see it all.

Comment: "_It seems that if one user starts a download at 50 Mbps and a 2nd user needs to download something, the ASA should then allocate 25 Mbps to each user. Is this something I have to configure manually?_" it doesn't work that way. Packets are routed regardless of any other packets. It is a first come, first served, unless you have configured some type of QoS.

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue up-stream of your pix/asa. If the ISP's gear is not policing traffic properly -- i.e. large buffers -- then one connection can seriously degrade all others.

Comment: @RickyBeam , when we upgraded from 20 to 50 Mbps, our Cisco 2621 router was changed out to an ISP-owned Cisco 2911. We don't have control over the config. I don't believe the modem was changed out. Could that be part of the problem too? I can dl large files and stream video at home without this problem.

Comment: @user208145 What does downloading at home have to do with the issue?  Seriously asking, in case I missed something.

Comment: @JesseP. just as a comparison. I have 100 Mbps download speeds at home. I can download an XBox update at full speed and still stream video, browse the internet, etc., so my equipment can allocate bandwidth accordingly. I'm puzzled as to why this enterprise hardware doesn't do that natively.

Comment: It does do it natively. There's just something we're not seeing. Have you contacted the ISP to open a trouble ticket so they can rule out their stuff from the equation?

Comment: Initially we did, and that's when the new router was installed. But at that time, we were still nowhere near being able to swap in the ASA at that point, so it was assumed the problem dividing the bandwidth among users was the fault of the old PIX.

Comment: @user208145 I'd open a ticket with your ISP and give them the symptoms, and tell them you can't find any configuration mistakes on your own equipment to justify it, so you want them to verify that they're handling traffic correctly on the edge router.

Comment: Following up on this...  Have you contacted your ISP and had them investigate this yet?  If so, what was their response?

Comment: Not yet. Will address Monday or Tuesday. Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: @user208145 Cool. Good luck and let us know what they come back with.

Comment: @user208145 Are we still on hold, waiting for your ISP's investigation?

Comment: They made a config change today around noon and I tested it during an open window a little bit ago, with no success. They're very slow to reply.

Comment: @user208145 If they made a change the must see the problem, suggesting it is something on their end that they can control. I'm curious to know what it is that they changed (even though it didn't work).

Comment: They didn't say what they changed, and we don't own the router to compare configs. It's very frustrating. It's been 30+ hours since the last communication from them without word.

Comment: @user208145 Did this get fixed by your ISP yet?

Comment: Nope. I'm gonna try to get some corporate cajones behind this issue. Fortunately, we're moving buildings within a year and I'm gonna recommend we seek out a different ISP. We're only a few miles from a municipal gigabit network. Maybe that'll expand some in the next year.

Comment: @user208145 Good luck.  Hopefully it gets resolved one way or another. Sorry we couldn't just solve it here.